# FindBugs: Possible null pointer dereference

Tags: java, findbugs

Hi I have the following method:

```
protected boolean shouldCheckLimit() {
    if (startDate == null || endDate == null) {
        return true;
    }
    final Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (startDate <= currentTime && currentTime < endDate) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that findBugs found the following problem:

```
Possible null pointer dereference of TimeIntervalLimit.startDate in com.bet.blues.limit.TimeIntervalLimit.shouldCheckLimit() [Scary(8), Normal
```

I have to mention that startDate and endDate are Long variables.
I tried to add checks for null inside if condition, also I tried to use longValue() method, but with no result. 
Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem? Could be a bug on fndBugs side?

Comment: Why don't you send `startDate` and `endDate` as parameters? `shouldCheckLimit(long startDate, long endDate){}`

Comment: *"Could be a bug on fndBugs side?"* Unlikely, [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). I'm having trouble believing you're getting that error with the code above, perhaps you got the error with an earlier version of the code?

Comment: Might be a workaround but why don't you use the "long" data type instead of the "Long" object type?

Comment: (Just wondering, why do people think that "possible null pointer dereference" is a helpful thing to check for? Seems like it adds a lot more noise than signal)

Comment: Your `startDate` and `endDate` are global variables. Anything can happen to them (including getting nullify) while getting the currentTime? Try the @UmaKanth suggestion and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 5):

You get the error because `startDate` (and also `endDate`) might be `null`. But you checked them for `null`, so that shouldn't be possible, right?

The answer is that both are global and might be set to `null` at any time by another thread.